# How to Find minimum and maximum in Data?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm using a data, I need to find the maximum value between the points 15000-20000.

```
data = Import["HNZ.dat"]
line = Flatten[data];
ListLinePlot[line, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Seismology Graphic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Max@line[[15000 ;; 20000]]
Min@line[[15000 ;; 20000]]
```

Comment: [`MinMax@line[[15000 ;; 20000]]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html)

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my answer if possible.